# How can I identify this popup face?

Tags: faces, lsp-mode, lsp-ui

[image: A picture of a snippet of rust code, with a popup window partially formatted but with a lingering light background]

I'm trying to find the face that applies to this tooltip in LSP in rust-mode with rust-analyzer, but I'm not seeing anything when I search on:

- tooltip
- lsp
- popup
- posframe
- lsp-rust-analyze
- faces
- lsp-ui

If there's a general method that works to identify faces you can't put the cursor on, or if someone knows what that annoyingly light background face is, I would love the help.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this is lsp-ui-doc-background.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, which is **how** to identify.

Comment: @Drew 

I am answering this

> or if someone knows what that annoyingly light background face is

Comment: OK. But FWIW, your answer would be even better if you mentioned how you found out what the face is.

Comment: Unfortunately nothing by that name comes up in the customization search, and `lsp-ui-doc-background` isn't a face that my copy of Emacs knows of.